# Cannot upload sketch to Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-nano, ide, windows

I've been using Arduino UNO for quite sometime and brought a new Arduino Nano. When I connected it to my computer, the power usb lit up and the blink sketch started running ( as expected of course).

Now I opened up the IDE and switched boards. But when I try to upload code to my Nano I get an error-

> avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\.\COM3": The system cannot find the file specified.

Clearly the IDE can't see my board. Uploading to my UNO goes fine. The serial port option is greyed out so I can't change it.

I have searched extensively online for a solution and have found none. This must be either a very unique issue or a very simple one.

Comment: Is it a genuine Arduino Nano or a cheap Chinese clone Nano?

Comment: @Majenko most probably a clone. I don't see anything written on the board. And the same coloured power and pin13 LED further confirm the fact. Have I done a mistake??

Comment: No, but it will need different drivers. CH340G

Comment: @Majenko I bought it online. The seller listed it a genuine one, but I just noticed that. BTW a google search for CH340G shows up differrent adapters. Do I need to buy an external adapted to program it??

Comment: Check the numbers on the chip on the underside first.

Comment: yes its CH340G...

Comment: So download and install those drivers then. Then Windows should identify it and give you a COM port to use.

Comment: @Majenko  did download them. Tried installing. Nothing happened...

Comment: I find it hard to believe that nothing happened. Did windows try and identify the hardware? Is there an unidentified or failed device in the device manager? Did windows make any sounds when you plugged the Nano in?

Comment: No sounds no devices in device manager. I installed the driver and it said pre-installed the drivers. Just nothing happened. is that bcz I'm on Win10.

Comment: Are you using a cable with no data wires in it?

Comment: @Majenko I don't know. Its a new cable I bought off at a local shop just half an hour ago. It powers up the Nano. But I'm not sure about how many wires are in it

Comment: Do you not have more than one cable? You should have a drawer full of USB cables. Everyone has a drawer full of USB cables.

Comment: @Majenko I **had** a drawer full of USB cables. In fact I kept a usb b type cable for charging my wireless headpiece but it went missing. BTW I tried connecting a phone using the same USB cable and guess what, nothing happened, the phone is just charging and my PC didn't detect a thing. So its a cable fault I assume

Comment: Certainly sounds like it. You can get cables without data wires that are purely for charging small devices (not phones and things which use the data wires to identify the charger and get more current).

Comment: @Majenko and yes the cable it was. Borrowed a cable from my neighbor and the Nano is working perfectly fine. Thanks. Please state that as an answer so I can mark it

Comment: I solved the problem, followed this: "http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Burn-a-Bootloader-to-Clone-Arduino-Nano-30/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have a clone not a genuine Arduino Nano. They use a different USB chip and require different drivers. Install the CH340 drivers.

Secondly your cable is bad. It sounds like one with no data wires in it used for powering or charging small low-powered devices like bluetooth headsets etc. Replace the cable with a proper one.

Answer (score 4):

When using a cheap knockoff Nano, it seems that in the newer versions of the Arduino IDE (at least in 1.8.8), you may need to select "ATmega328P (Old bootloader)" from the Processor options under the Tools menu in order to upload sketches.

Comment: Phew. I never would have guessed this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this error a few times and renaming the serial port fixed the problem in my case. I documented the steps in detail in Tip #4 of this blog post: https://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2020/10/16/cant-open-device-com-access-is-denied-arduino-upload/

Answer (score -1):

I don't really see a question in the OP, but here is the immediate answer:

Go into Control Panel..Device manager.  Open the Ports (COM & LPT) and see what you have.  It should be listed.

If it is a CH340 port it will just give a COMx number.

If you have the genuine article then it will actually say so and give you the COMx number to use.

If no COM ports show then try switching out the cable.  Power cycle the Arduino and try again.

There aren't that many moving parts in this, but sometimes, Windows gets confused and a Windows reboot might be necessary.  That usually only happens if you unplug and replug the Arduino too many times for Windows to keep track of.